# How to display part of video use TextureView?

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, textureview

My video datasource is 1920*1080, and my textureView is 622px * 540px. and I only want to display part of the video in the TextureView. How to do this? please help me ,  thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add some relevant code if you have tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it,  i want it. https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/video-crop/blob/master/library/src/com/dd/crop/TextureVideoView.java